# Android Studio - Emulator not there

Tags: android, emulation

I am completely new to Android Studio. I installed it on Windows and running through the first tutorials on the Android website. In the "Run Your App" tutorial you are explained how you can use an AVD emulator. Simply stated, I cannot find an emulator in my IDE. Under the "Tools" in the Menu Bar I should click on "Android", which simply is not there.. The path I need to take to initialize the emulator simply does not exist.. Can anyone help me?

In the following image, under Kotlin it should say Android.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wait for your Gradle build to finish. Once the loader down the bottom has gone away, then the Android option should appear in tools.

Comment: Thank you Alex.. I did not know where to look.. With your help I found the problem. Apparently the problem was the following: gradle sync failed failed to find target with hash string 'android-26.. So I installed the 26 from SDK Manager and now it works. Awesome!

Comment: Glad to be able to help someone :)